# independent sub spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space with dimV=4.

$$S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} , R=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$$

both are INDEPENDED.

I need to prove that there exists a vector $$v\in V$$
such that $$R\cup \{v\} $$ $$S\cup \{v\} $$
will both be a basis of V.

Comment: That's obviously false.

Comment: What is independed?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For example, take $S$ to be a linearly dependent set.

Comment: both of them are Independed its given in the question

Comment: @OmerGafla Yes, after you edit it in...

Comment: it was in the title but thanks anyway